# Fullscreen Android "Unfortunately application has stopped" Why?

Tags: android, crash, android-fullscreen

I wanted to implement in my application the fullscreen. I found this code to do it:

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

or through the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

well none goes. Both makes my app crash when I launch it. The error is "Unfortunately application has stopped". Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Comment: copy error logs from logcat, code you've posted here works fine

Comment: Do you have your activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes i have it. I have even a splash screen activity..could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to make your activity FULL_SCREEN

1. Looking for find: styles.xml in res\values\ add

   ```
   <style name="NoTitle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Open file Manifest
   Looking for application

Add

```
android:theme="@style/NoTitle">
```

It looks like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoTitle" >
```

Comment: code by End.Game works, the problem isn't in set-fullscreen operations

Comment: However when i come back home i'll try this alternative you posted.. Maybe writing the style code goes..

Comment: The splash screen could be  a problem?

Answer (score 0):

put your code BEFORE super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```css
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```